# How to implement material text input in the material date picker in react native?

Tags: react-native

Hello I am using material date picker in react native.

```
<DatePicker
   // style={{width: 200}}
    date={this.state.date}
    mode="date"
    placeholder="Date Of Birth"
    format="YYYY-MM-DD"
    minDate="2016-05-01"
    maxDate="2016-06-01"
    confirmBtnText="Confirm"
     iconSource = {uri=require('/root/VS_Code/JavascriptProjects/MatrimonialAppSvn/MatrimonialApp/assets/Images/dateofbirth.png')}

    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
    customStyles={{
      dateInput:{borderWidth: 0,marginLeft:40},
      dateIcon: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        top: 4,

        marginRight:200,
        marginLeft: 0
      },
      // dateInput: {
      //   marginLeft: 36
      // }
      // ... You can check the source to find the other keys.
    }}
    onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date})}}
  />
```

For the date input I need to implement material date picker,where the hint escalates slighly up on focus. I know it can be done separately with placing an icon and view independently, but then I need to open datepicker on its click. If the above is not possible then is it possible to open date picker on click of my icon and implement it,if yes how ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can open a DatePicker on Click of any icon. You can achieve it by overlapping the view. Put your DatePicker on your icon (on which you want to open DatePicker). Please see below code. It may help you.

```
render(){

  return(
  <View style={{ width: 25, height: 25 }}>

                            <View style={{ width: '100%',height:'100%' }}>
                                <Image style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                                 source={icons.IC_CALENDAR} //add your icon here
                                 /> 
                            </View>
                            <DatePicker
                                style={{ 
                               position:'absolute',top:0,right:0,left:0,bottom:0 
                                }}
                                 date={this.state.date}
                                 mode="date"
                                placeholder="Date Of Birth"
                                format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                                minDate="2016-05-01"
                                maxDate="2016-06-01"
                               confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                                cancelBtnText="Cancel"

                                customStyles={{
                                    dateIcon: {
                                        position: 'absolute',
                                        left: 0,
                                        top: 4,
                                        width: 0,
                                        height: 0,
                                        marginLeft: 0
                                    }, //give width and height 0 to date 
 icon to invisible the date icon

                                }}
                                onDateChange={(date) => {
                                  this.setState({date: date})
                                }}
                            />
                        </View>
)
}
```